# How to access child chart template defined within _helpers.tpl , from parent chart's _helpers.tpl

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am deploying mysql database & webapp frontend app through helm chart.

I am deploying mysql through dependency chart & put the chart configuration within Charts/ directory .

After deploying mysql , I have to use mysql connection string (mysql service name) within webapp deployment , how can I access mysql service name (subchart) from parent chart (webapp)

within sublass/child class (mysql) helpers.tpl file I have defined mysql service name as below

```
{{- define "mysql.fullname" -}}
{{- $name := default .Chart.Name .Values.nameOverride -}}
{{- printf "%s-%s" .Release.Name $name | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" -}}
{{- end -}}
```

This above same template I have to include in my parent chart's helpers.tpl file.

How I can achieve it

Comment: I think you can just use them directly? I haven't tried in a while but I think define block names are global, that's why it has the chart name on them in the first place.

Comment: The one thing you'll run into is that `.Chart` is from the current context.  You should technically be able to `{{ template "mysql.fullname" .}}` from anywhere, but it will return the equivalent name for your top-level application (not MySQL) and it won't see a `.Values.mysql.nameOverride`.

Comment: @DavidMaze: yes I understood your point , .Chart.Name will be picked up from parent/top-level (Not MYSQL) ,so what's the way out here , If I want to use service name of mysql from top-level application?

Comment: Hard-coding `{{ printf "%s-mysql" .Release.Name }}` will be correct, unless you hit one of the corner cases this handles (the name-override parameter, a very long release name).  Duplicating the template logic will definitely be correct but require more code.

Comment: A lot of people have the exact same [issue](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3920)

Comment: @Satwik you need to have requirements.yaml ```dependencies:
  - name:sqlchartname
    version: "1.0.1"
    repository: "file://../sqlchartfolderpath"
    # repository: "published_sql_chart_path"``` in your webapp helm chart. And that yaml you need tell the dependency on mysql subchart. Once you do that, you just  need to access the mysql connection variable in webapp template like this ```{{ template 'sqlconnection' - }}.